# Free Linux text editor with syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

I know text editor and IDE questions have pretty much been beat to death, but most of the answers I've found to this question are Windows and Mac specific, and also aren't always free. I've just started rails development and I'm looking for a light-weight text-editor that supports syntax highlighting. I know there is RubyMine, RadRails, and Netbeans. I'll probably always use one of them for big projects, however, sometimes I prefer to stay away from the IDEs (and all the project .xml .config workspace files they create, and the overhead of opening a file that isn't located in a specific "project") and just use a simple text editor. I had been using Scribes in the past for this but it doesn't have highlighting for .rhtml. I've heard people struggle with gedit as well, and I'm nowhere near desperate enough to be running Notepad++ under wine. Sublime seems to be popular but isn't free. Am I being too needy? Is there anything out there that meets the following criteria:

1. Runs on linux
2. Has syntax highlighting for rails (.rhtml, .erb, .rake, etc.)
3. Is lightweight (not only the look and feel but also I don't want it generating all the unnecessary baggage that IDEs do)
4. Provides the basic features that pretty much all text editors do (I know this sounds vague and stupid but to be more specific all text editors should give you the option to specify the encoding, replace tabs with spaces, specify tab size, specify the default new line characters, etc. etc.)
5. Free. Open source is a nice to have but not a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also Gmate is nice. It's Gedit with a number of plugins which make it behave like textmate.

https://github.com/gmate/gmate

Answer (score 5):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is an amazing text editor. You can use it for free but they show you a little nag-screen every know and then.

// Check out the [packet management](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control), too
// [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk-tFn2Ix6g) is Paul Irish demonstrating live linting and Zen Coding in Sublime

Comment: A lot of people seem to love Sublime; what does it have to offer that other editors do not?

Comment: It's a simple (like TextMate, gedit etc.) but crazy fast text editor. Almost every part of it is configurable and/or extendable and it's cross-platform. It has a lots of useful features like multi-line editing (check out the demonstration on their homepage).

I switched from [Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com/) to Sublime mostly because of the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Now, in the Ruby community, the most popular editor is [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) which is hard to get started with, but once you get used to it you won't go back. It's light-weight, customizable, extendable, powerful and absolutely awesome.

Another popular one is, as @superlukas said, [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) which is good, but if you want to use it long term, you'll end up having to pay for it (it's distributed as a never-ending trial).

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 2 is what you are looking for just put in the command line :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2.
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sublime-text.

Then it will be in usr/lib/sublime-text-2.You can then do your path configurations from there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other options mentioned ( [vim/gvim](http://www.vim.org/download.php), [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/), and Gmate), take a look at [Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/).

It's an editor for Ruby, written in Ruby.  It's actually quite nice, although I tend to use Sublime and vim more these days.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely check this out. I like the fact that you can write your own plug-ins in Ruby.